# I want my screen setup back

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 20.10

I have a laptop with docking & 3 screens. It's Ubuntu 20.10 and it's a fresh install from October. The screens have been set up at one time via the Settings->Screen Display and were working fine.

Recently my PC went into sleep mode or something like that and when it woke up I only had one screen (don't really remember the details). I had stuff I wanted to do so I didn't reset but did some xrandr commands to get my screen correct again. That worked.

However, this apparently has caused something to be permanently saved. When I now log into ubuntu it has only 2 screens (curiously it has 3 *before* logging in) and I have to do a:

```
xrandr --auto
xrandr --output DP-0 --left-of DP-2
```

to get it how I want it. But trying settings->Display can no longer do any changes as it says "Changes Cannot be Applied" and underneath that "This could be due hardware limitations." as soon as I try to make changes.

I've seen suggestions on running an xrandr script at startup but as it was working just fine before, I'd rather get back to that situation. But how?

Comment: The display settings in Ubuntu aren't remembering anything. It's ridiculous, the posts here have been nonstop (and most of them, like this one, without answers). I really wish they'd fix their UX bugs.

Comment: I found a workaround: I changed my display drivers from the proprietary ones to the open source ones in Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers and now it's working fine again. Not really a good solution I suppose, but good enough for me right now.

Comment: The above workaround wasn't really good. The open source drivers sometimes caused crashes of both the whole UI or individual applications. Today (now on Ubuntu 22.10) I reverted back to the proprietary NVIDIA drivers, and now everything seems fine again. Hope it stays that way...